# Rules about/against runners interracting with the ball in baseball?

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb, major-leagues

Say Bob is up to bat, Peter is pitching, and Ryan is a runner on 1st base (part of Bob's team).

Scenario #1:
If Bob the batter hits the ball into Ryan the runner, what happens? Is Ryan out, or do things proceed as normal, with the ball in play?

Scenario #2:
Same as scenario #1, but before the ball hits Ryan the runner, it flies off Peter the pitcher's glove (because he failed to catch it). Same question about whether Ryan is out, or what happens.

Scenario #3:
Pick what happened in Scenario #1 or #2. However, this time, Ryan catches the ball and holds it on him while running around the bases. Are there any rules that mess with Ryan in this scenario?

My question is in particular about the rules in American MLB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In #1, the runner is out; [MLB Rule 5.09(b)](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf):

> The runner is out when: [...] (7) He is touched by a fair ball in fair territory before the ball has gone through, or by, an infielder and no other infielder has a chance to make a play on the ball.

In #2 and #3, the runner is not out purely because they were hit by the ball. If they *intentionally* interfere with the ball, they are out; Rule 6.01(a):

> It is interference by a batter or a runner when: [...] (10) He [...] intentionally interferes with a thrown ball
>
> [...]
>
> PENALTY FOR INTERFERENCE: The runner is out and the ball is dead.

The ball counts as "thrown" in this case as it touched a fielder, even though it wasn't really a throw.

Comment: Note that the rule is slightly different from just "hit by the batted ball", as your pasted rule makes clear - if the infield is in, for example, and the runner is hit *after* a fielder could have fielded the ball but didn't (say it goes under the shortstop's glove, but doesn't contact the glove) the runner is still not out.